# Filtering Data with WP_Meta_Query

Tags: wordpress, meta-query

I want to search restaurant by their sit capacity. I will select a number from dropdown and I have to show restaurants between minimum and maximum sit capacity. I tried below code. But it always shows no results.

```
$_seating_capacity  = $_GET['seating_capacity'] != '' ? $_GET['seating_capacity'] : '';
$_standing_capacity = $_GET['standing_capacity'] != '' ? $_GET['standing_capacity'] : '';
$_neighborhood      = $_GET['neighborhood'] != '' ? $_GET['neighborhood'] : '';
// Start the Query
$v_args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'Dinings', // your CPT
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array( 'key'     => 'min_capacity_sit',
                       'value'   => $_seating_capacity,
                       'compare' => '=>',
                       'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                ),
                //AND Conditation
                array( 'key'     => 'max_capacity_sit',
                       'value'   => $_seating_capacity,
                       'compare' => '<=',
                       'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                )
            ),

            //OR Conditation
            array( 'key'     => 'max_capacity_stand',
                   'value'   => $_standing_capacity,
                   'compare' => '<=',
                   'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            )
        ),
        //AND Conditation
        array( 'key' => 'neighborhood', 'value' => $_neighborhood, 'compare' => 'Like', ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Your input is not escaped, this can be unsafe. Here is a guide to get you started [Validating Sanitizing and Escaping User Data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data)

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your compares you use `=>` but the syntax is `>=`.

Also this is quite a query. If there are other problems I recommend you comment out every step. And turn on 1 step at a time debugging also one step at a time.

[documentation of WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Comment: @weaver if my answer solved your problem don't forget to mark it as solved.